# is it feasible to plot a swarm plot for data-points around 50000 in jupyter-notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, swarmplot

I have categorical data containing col1 and col2. Here col1 is divided into 5 categories. Data points corresponding to this dataset is 50000 i.e no. of rows. I want to plot a swarmplot using seaborn swarmplot function in jupyter notebook. But it is taking time. So, my query is just that can it will plot the swarmplot. If it wil plot then how much time it will take to plot for such huge dataset.

Comment: 50000 points on a swarmplot is a lot. Note that depending on the size of the points, they would not all fit within the axes. However, I just timed `sns.swarmplot("x", "y", data=df, s=1)` with `df` having 50000 rows and it took 50 seconds.

Comment: Thank, I will try it. It means large points decrease the size of point.